# k combinations from n

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

The combination can be formed with 3 digits from 1,2,3,4 such a way that **d1 < d2 < d3** and so on.

Eg: 123,124,234 ...

n = 4 and k = 3

How do we do this ? Any clues as to how do we do this **n** choose **k** in java ?

Comment: Original poster, you're only cheating yourself if you don't show at least a first attempt. This way we can best see where your misconceptions lie and better be able to help  you.

Comment: Nah, it is not a home work. I just got a puzzles book and I am just brushing thru it.

Comment: @abracabra: my comment had nothing to do with this being homework or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this must be homework so only hints.

1. There has to be a lib somewhere in JAVA modeling combinatorics algorithms.
2. If there isn't, you can always write one and use that. It's easy to do, get out Pascal's Triangle and get to work.